# How to detect a white paper on a white background with opencv

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, object-detection

I use the OpenCV library for detecting a white page from a book. Finding 4 corners on dark surfaces, but the white background finds only 3 corners. How can I find a way to find 4 corners or read a page on a white background?

Or could you suggest another library that I can use outside of Opencv?

I use the following code to find the contours.

```
    Mat grayImage = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat cannedImage = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat dilate = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayImage, grayImage, new Size(5.0, 5.0), 0.0);
    Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, grayImage, 20.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_TRIANGLE);
    Imgproc.Canny(grayImage, cannedImage, 75.0, 200.0);
    Imgproc.dilate(cannedImage, dilate, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(10.0, 10.0)));
```

How can I change this code?

I test my code with these photos.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Have a nice day.

Comment: @zindarod I added pictures. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the whole page or the portion containing the text?

Comment: Thanks a lot @zindarod , I will convert this code to Java, after try it in my project. Also which OpenCV version did you use?

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    lab = cv2.split(lab)

    binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(lab[2], 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 7)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    binary = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel,iterations=3)

    contours = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

    points = np.concatenate(contours)

    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(points)

    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255))

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

[image: result2]

Comment: Thanks a lot @zindarod , I will convert this code to Java, after try it in my project. Also which OpenCV version did you use?

Comment: Also I have another question. How can I get the edges of the written notebook sheet?  @zindarod

Comment: Great, @zindarod! How to select the whole page (one page) borders containing the text, as you have asked?